# Get hadoop configuration in Java util

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm writing a Java utility that needs to access the DFS, so I need a `Configuration` object.
When I create one simply by using

`Configuration conf = new Configuration()`

it doesn't seem to find the DFS, and just uses the local file system; printing

`fs.getHomeDirectory()`

gives my local home directory. I've tried adding 
core-site.xml,mapred-site.xml,yarn-site.xml,and hdfs-site.xml to the Configuration as resources, but it doesn't change anything. What do I need to do to get it to pick up the HDFS settings?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason why it's pointing to your local file system is `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` is not added properly.  Below code snippet will help you.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("file:///etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml")); // Replace with actual path
conf.addResource(new Path("file:///etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml")); // Replace with actual path

Path pt = new Path("."); // HDFS Path
FileSystem fs = pt.getFileSystem(conf);

System.out.println("Home directory :"+fs.getHomeDirectory());
```

Update :

Above option should've worked, It seems some issues in the configuration file or path. You have another option instead of adding configuration files using addResource method, use set method. Open your core-site.xml file and find the value of `fs.defaultFS`. Use set method instead of addResource method.

```
conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://<Namenode-Host>:<Port>");  // Refer you core-site.xml file and replace <Namenode-Host> and <Port> with your cluster namenode and Port (default port number should be `8020`).
```

Comment: I was doing this, but not putting 'file:///' at the beginning. I have now added that but it still can't access HDFS. The paths to the config files are definitely correct.

Comment: Pls see the updated answer. First option should've worked. Try the second option.

Answer (score 4):

To get access to the File system you have to use the configuration and a file system as outlined below

1. Get the instance of Configuration
2. Get the HDFS instance

   ```
   Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

   FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://"+HadoopLocation+":8020"), configuration);
   ```

In this case HadoopLocation is the location in which you have your hadoop server (Possibly Localhost)